# How do you change the color of a Telerik GridGroupByExpression arrow?

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, telerik, radgrid

Does anybody know how to change the color of GridGroupByExpression arrow shown at the link below?
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/groupby/outlookstyle/defaultcs.aspx

I haven't figured out how to change the color from the default black. I'd like to change the several I have in my project to white (in the above demo it's a shade of blue) but I have no clue how to pull this off (the demo doesn't show how to change it), so if anybody knows how I can accomplish this I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to just subscribe to the OnColumnCreated event and use the following code-snippet:

```
        if (e.Column is GridGroupSplitterColumn)
        {
            (e.Column as GridGroupSplitterColumn).ExpandImageUrl = "image.gif";
            (e.Column as GridGroupSplitterColumn).CollapseImageUrl = "image.gif";
        }
```

The images that are used for these groups are the "SingleMinus.gif" and "SinglePlus.gif" images that you can find within the local Telerik install folder. They should be found in the Skins/[Skin Name]/Grid/ folder.

Comment: I moved past this question since I couldn't get an answer, but when I saw yours I reread my question and realized I misstated it. I meant to say in the first paragraph that I'm trying to change the *color of the arrow*, not the arrow image itself. I do thank you for taking the time to try to answer this though. I'll try to get into the image directory to see if I can find an arrow with the color I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@Kswift : we can not change the colour of an image , we have to use the OnColumnCreated event what Carl suggested ,if you want to change the color of an image , you can do it with any photo editor and than use the above method to bind with the grid.